# Is it possible to run ADB on multiple devices using Hyper-V?

Tags: automation, virtualization

What I would like to do is use Hyper-V to set up N number of VM's, each one being used to run a different set of tests on a different Android device. It seems like Hyper-V doesn't accept the input of the USB device.

My question is: Is it possible to run ADB on multiple devices using Hyper-V? If so, how?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a limitation that is specific to Hyper-V. Do you have the option of using other VM solutions?

Comment: Yes, I do now... Lol... Is there one in particular you'd suggest?

Comment: [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/overview.html) are both free or there are plenty of options to pay for. I run [VMware Fusion 5](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html) on my Macbook but haven't tried ADB yet. I don't know whether either free option will do what you need but they're very easy to try. Does anyone else know how well these interact with ADB devices connected to the host?

Answer (score 1):

See the [USB access from guest in Hyper-V](https://serverfault.com/q/355949/63156) question on ServerFault — in short, Hyper-V does not provide any way to access host USB ports from guests. There are some workarounds — mostly “USB over Ethernet” solutions.

Another option which could work for some use cases is to enable Wireless ADB on the devices, and then access them via the network.